# Why can't a Raspi 4 load as big a SDL2 texture as a 3B+?

Tags: pi-3b+, pi-4, gpu, sdl

I've been developing a game in C using SDL2. It works fine on a Raspberry Pi 3B+. On a Raspberry Pi 4 with 4 GB of RAM, it fails to load one of the graphics because "textures are limited to 4096x4096" and one graphic is larger than this. It's 6720 x 280.

It seems odd that the model with the lesser amount of RAM is able to load the graphic. Note. I have changed the amount of RAM allocated to the GPU on the Raspi 4 to 256 MB but it doesn't seem to make a difference,

Comment: Is it really a 3B+ vs 4 difference? Worth checking if it's a OS/software problem, are they both running the same version of the same OS with the same packages installed?  I guess you tried booting the Pi 4 from the 3B SD card?  If not give that a go.  If it's not that maybe something to do with the Pi 4's  VideoCore VI

Comment: I installed the same Raspbian OS on both, the current one on the downloads page. I also installed Clang (V7) and VS Code, so I can compile on both. Each has its own SD card but I've kept them as similar as possible.  I have succeeded in loading the textures on the Pi 4 and got the game running there but only by editing the graphic files to half the width and twice the height.